# Show current call stack without breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I need something like this [Eclipse - showing full call stack (like when it hits breakpoint in debugger) without putting in breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711954/eclipse-showing-full-call-stack-like-when-it-hits-breakpoint-in-debugger-wit) :
Need to show all code calls that have been performed without breakpoints at present.
But for C# .Net. I use MS VS, but if you know other tools with such features - I will be glad.

**ADDED:**
I want something like log of all calls but without implementing logger or introducing everywhere code Debug.WriteLine("StackTrace: '{0}'", Environment.StackTrace);

Comment: You want to get this call stack at which locations? The description is not exactly clear, and there is little information to be gleaned from that linked question unless you already know how Eclipse works (and I don't). What would you propose to *do* with this information? Are you just trying to build a call graph?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c

Comment: @user1175338, what about this issue? Is the Resharper tool helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool Resharper has the Stack Trace Explorer window which can display stack traces information:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Windows__Stack_Trace_Explorer.html

Answer (score 1):

Environment stack trace does what you're looking for

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may be poorly expressed, but I need all performed calls from a code(log of calls). It means that this code will be everywhere at all finite points of calls: Debug.WriteLine("StackTrace: '{0}'", Environment.StackTrace);

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean. You can use it in a condition if you don't want to call it every time, or use only at points you want it called with an appropriate condition.

Comment: I worked with project with legacy code and I don't know this code. I want to see history of all performed calls at current moment.